# Storing arrays in rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I use the following snippet to create a set of checboxes in the view

```
<div class="field">
<b> <%= f.label :scenario %><br /></b>
  <% Scenarios.all.each do |scenario| -%>
    <%= check_box_tag 'umvoxq[scenario][]', scenario.id, @umvoxq.scenario.include?(scenario.id.to_s) -%>
    <%= label_tag :scenario, scenario.name -%>
  <% end -%>
</div>
```

When i save the model the values are successfully stored in DB and retrieved back on the page.But the format it saves in DB is :

```
| ---
- '3'
- '4'
 |
```

Its like a huge string with new line character. My column in DB is varachar and i was expecting to be `3,4`

My model is

```
class Umvoxq < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I also tried using

```
serialize:scenario
```

in the model but it didnt change the formatting. Is there a way i can correct format ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother on format anyway it is stored it in YAML. The best way of doing it is

- make column data type as text [Because some time it may not fit varchar]
- make column as serialize in your model as like below

> ```
> serialize :scenario, Array
> ```

That's it. So when you are accessing scenario from Umvoxq then you will get data in array.

P.S: If you don't want to change the data type of the column then you have to convert the params you are getting from form to string[like 2,3,4] and store it to db.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little bit offtop but take a look on key-value storages like Redis or hstore (build upon PostgreSQL). I think that they will be well fitted there.